# Clean Swift architecture for SwiftUI application: Assign values from Interactor to AppState class

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am building a small application whose purpose is to fetch real time data from an api and display them in a SwiftUI view. I thought to base it on the clean Swift architecture and to store the values in an AppState class, while including the business logic in an interactor. The workflow is the following:
The view calls the interactor function to fetch and update the data > the interactor saves the data in the AppState class > The view shows the data from AppState.
The first issue I have encountered is how the interactor updates AppState.

So far I could solve the issue just by making AppState a singleton. So I wanted to ask you if there are better ways to do it and if the way I have structured my code is good practice. Here is an example:

My View

```
struct MyView: View {

    var appState = AppState.shared
    var interactor = Interactor()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text(appState.temperature)
        }
        .onAppear {
            interactor.updateData()          
        }
    }

}
```

My AppState

```
public class AppState: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AppState()
    @Published var temperature: Double = 0
}
```

My Interactor

```
public class Interactor {

    var appState = AppState.shared
    
    func updateData() {
        // some code to fetch data
        self.appState.temperature = data.temperature ?? 0
    }

}
```

Comment: This link, gives you a good start in explaining how to manage your data in your app: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app   IMHO, the `class Interactor` does not seems to do much, except 
force you to constantly make sure it updates the `AppState`, which you cannot observed in `class Interactor`, and 
ensure it does it on the main thread. It does not seem to follow what Apple explain in the link above. But then again, this is just my opinion.

Comment: A singleton isn’t clean architecture. They are generally considered bad practice you can read all about it online there are many articles and discussions. Look into dependency injection.

Comment: A singleton is, of course, the perfect solution. Note that in apps, especially iOS, UIKit, almost everything is a singleton (notably .. "the app" as well as screen, gps, bluetooth, etc etc).  These days if you want synced data, consider using a synced data system (whether amplify, firebase or whatever - so many). (Of course, those are all implemented as singletons in the app side.)

Comment: *So I wanted to ask you if there are better ways to do it and if the way I have structured my code is good practice.* is asking for Opinions, which is not allowed. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) & [Don't advise on off-topic questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to build an app using clean architecture with SwiftUI, you can look at this example I created [here](https://github.com/maykonmeneghel/Clean-SwiftUI.git), where the layers are completely isolated. I explain each of the layers better [here](https://medium.com/@maykonmeneghel_55360/clean-architecture-swiftui-9bb39619af70).

However, the way I built a clean architecture using SwiftUI was by creating four well-isolated layers: Domain, Infra, External, and Presentation.

In the Domain layer I do it in the following way:

```swift
// Domain/Entities/ContentEntity.swift
struct ContentEntity {
    var theme: String
    var url: String
    var level: String
}

// Domain/Repositories/ContentRepository.swift
protocol ContentRepository {
    func fetchContents() -> [ContentEntity]
}

// Domain/UseCases/FetchContentsUseCase.swift
protocol FetchContentsUseCase {
    func call() -> [ContentEntity]
}

struct FetchContentsUseCaseImpl: FetchContentsUseCase {
    var repository: ContentRepository
    
    func call() -> [ContentEntity] {
        repository.fetchContents()
    }
}
```

In the Infra layer I do this:

```swift
// Infra/Datasources/ContentDatasource.swift
protocol ContentDatasource {
    func fetchContents() -> [ContentModel]
}

// Infra/Models/ContentModel.swift
struct ContentModel {
    var theme: String
    var url: String
    var level: String
}

// Infra/Repositories/ContentRepositoryImpl.swift
struct ContentRepositoryImpl: ContentRepository {
    var datasource: ContentDatasource
    
    func fetchContents() -> [ContentEntity] {
        let contents: [ContentModel] = datasource.fetchContents()
        return contents.map({ ContentMapper.toEntity(from: $0) })
    }
}

// Infra/Mappers/ContentMapper.swift
struct ContentMapper {
    static func toEntity(from content: ContentModel) -> ContentEntity {
        return ContentEntity(theme: content.theme, url: content.url, level: content.level)
    }
    
    static func toModel(from content: ContentEntity) -> ContentModel {
        return ContentModel(theme: content.theme, url: content.url, level: content.level)
    }
}
```

In the External layer I implement the Datasource and in the Presentation layer I just have a `ViewModel` that knows all the `UseCases` and that way, in the View I call the ViewModel which in turn will call the UseCase, which calls the Repository, which in turn calls the Datasource, which finally returns to view the processed information. This chain effect allows you to have different implementations of layers that can be easily switched.

Here is an example of the View:

```swift
// Presentation/ViewModels/ContentViewModel.swift
struct ContentViewModel {
    
     private var _fetchContentsUseCase: FetchContentsUseCase
    
     init(_ fetchContentsUseCase: FetchContentsUseCase) {
         self._fetchContentsUseCase = fetchContentsUseCase
     }
    
     func fetchContents() -> [ContentEntity] {
         return _fetchContentsUseCase.call()
     }
}

// Presentation/UI/ContentView.swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
     // MARK: Properties
     @Dependency(\.features.contentFeature.contentViewModel) var viewModel
    
     @State var contents: [ContentEntity] = []
    
     // MARK: - Body
     var body: some View {
         HStack {
             List {
                 ForEach(contents, id: \.url) { content in
                     Text(content.theme)
                 }
             }
         }
         .task {
             contents = viewModel.fetchContents()
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587