# Persisting polymorphic entity (existential type) in Swift Clean Architecture

Tags: swift, polymorphism, swift-protocols, clean-architecture, existential-type

I'm building a application in swift and I'm trying to follow clean architecture. In my domain layer, I have a protocol called `Source`, which represents any source of a particular entity (could be from network, from a local file, etc...):

```
protocol Source { // not the actual code, just a simple example
    func getData(id: String) -> Entity
}
```

The `getData` function returns an entity defined elsewhere in the domain layer. Therefore, `Source` acts somewhat like a repository for `Entity`, if I understand the repository pattern correctly.

However, `Source` will also act somewhat like an entity. There will be multiple implementations of `Source` (I think defined in the data layer), and the user can "install" and "uninstall" particular source, meaning the application has to store the list of sources that the user has installed.

For example...

```
struct LocalSource {
    let fileName: String
    
    func getData(id: String) -> Entity { /* whatever */ }
}

struct NetworkSource {
    let url: URL
    
    func getData(id: String) -> Entity { /* whatever */ }
}
```

The existential type `any Source` would be used throughout the app to represent sources.

So my question is, how would I go about persisting sources? Presumably, there would be some kind of `SourceRepository` protocol in the domain layer that persists `any Source` values. But I can't figure out how this would be implemented.

Ideally, whatever code is responsible for storing `Source`s would not have to know any actual implementations of `Source`. It's very important that it's easy to add new `Source` implementations, ideally without having to change the `SourceRepository` implementation. This means that it has to persist type information so that it can reconstruct the correct concrete `Source` implementation when data is retrieved from the repository.

I found [this](https://www.pointfree.co/blog/posts/78-reverse-engineering-swiftui-s-navigationpath-codability) great guide on encoding from/decoding to `any Codable`, preserving type information. However, this obviously requires `Codable` conformance in order to work. This is where my problem is: I could use this approach if the `Source` protocol inherited from `Codable`.

```
protocol Source: Codable { /* ... */ }
```

Therefore, `any Source` values could be encoded and decoded and stored in a database without losing any information.

However, this to me seems like it would mean there is some persistence-specific logic in the domain layer, which I know should be avoided.

Is there a better way to achieve this, or am I being too picky?

Comment: Hi, you are correct when you say that it is best to avoid any interaction with the datasource at the domain layer. This layer should only be used to maintain the business rule. The most correct thing would be for you to organize to have the Domain, Infra, External and Presentation layers well isolated, and this persistence happens only in the External layer, which is where the Datasource implementation takes place. I explained this separation more fully here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76461016/12460626